# Allow webcam/mic access with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, camera, webcam

I want to create a pop up that shows to the user when the camera/mic aren't activated that he has to allow access if he wants to continue and when he clicks allow, it will give access to the camera/Mic! but the problem that I can't find a built function to do that. help please !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mediaDevices https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Actually I want to create a button on my Html page if we click it, it allows camera/mic access. like a pop-up that shows and tells you if you click this button you will allow access to camera/mic

Comment: What I gave you gets the users media devices / opens their media devices. Once you do that by using on button click if you want. The page will ask the user if they want to allow access.